# Microphone not working Lenovo C930

Tags: lenovo, microphone

Please help me out.
Microphone not working in my Lenovo Yoga C930.
Tried quite of suggested solutions previously, but none look promising.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Any luck? you got it fixed by now?